# Can't hit breakpoint to one specific action in JetBrains Rider

Tags: .net, debugging, swagger, breakpoints, jetbrains-rider

My controller has a lot of actions. But One actions breakpoint not being hit when at debug mod.

I triggered other actions from swagger and those breakpoints were hit. But when I send request to that action, I get response directly.
I looked to attached process, also I looked is there any w3wp process. There is no.

I suspect about my request param. I try to send json in request. My controller action take List of a model.(Also I tried param as ConcurrentBag). If this is a issue how I can solve it?
if hitting breakpoints problem is not about that what is the problem and How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Yes it was about my action params. For solving I try [FromQuery] and I coluld debug with this attribute. But it is not appropriate for me. I want to send request once param object.
[TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body / for Action that take object List (.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357466/typeerror-failed-to-execute-fetch-on-window-request-with-get-head-method-c)
I open this question for solution. There is no problem with debugging or compiler.