# TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body / for Action that take object List (.Net)

Tags: .net, parameters, attributes, postman, swagger

I have controller action like this;

```
 [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ResultModel>> ToUnique(List<Model> models)
```

I want to send json data at swagger, swagger response to me this error that above. Json ınclude list.

firstly I tried [FromQuery] at param like this;

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ResultModel>> ToUnique([FromQuery]List<Model> models)
```

When this case I had to send every object as seperate in swagger request. Like this image;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyMzw.png)

also when I debug it realize action params couldnt convert so param List was empty.

How I can solve this problem I want use this action just with swagger or postman there is no request from other sides to this 'toUnique' action.

After that I tried [FromBody] attribute like fromquery and error happened again as expected.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: I solved this problem with [HttpPost] attribute instead [HttpGet] but I want to solution with [HttpGet] method.